# Are temporary urls to s3 objects also valid for cloudfront?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

If i create a temporary url to an s3 object, can I then change the domain to my cloudfront distribution and have the content still be available from cloudfront?

Comment: it looks quite simple to try and find out..

Answer (score 1):

**It won't work** if you simply change domain to CloudFront distribution in your S3 temporary url.

The approach is different with CloudFront. See the [Serving Private Content](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/2009-12-01/DeveloperGuide/index.html?PrivateContent.html) chapter of CloudFront Developer Guide..

The most relevant part:

> 1. Use the CloudFront control API to **create a CloudFront origin access identity**. For more information, see Creating a CloudFront
>      Origin Access Identity.
> 2. Use the Amazon S3 API (or your favorite Amazon S3 tool) to **update the ACL on your private objects** to give read permission to the
>      CloudFront origin access identity you just created. For a list of
>      Amazon S3 tools you can use, go to Amazon CloudFront Developer Tools. 
>      For more information about setting the ACL, see Modifying the ACL on
>      Your Private Content Objects.
> 3. **Set up a private content distribution** or streaming distribution (either create a new one or update an existing distribution). For more
>      information, see Setting Up a Private Content Distribution and
>      Streaming Distribution.
> 4. Use the Amazon S3 API (or your favorite Amazon S3 tool) to **update the ACL on your private objects to remove any read permission grants
>      for the public, leaving the read permission for the CloudFront origin
>      access identity**. For more information, see Modifying the ACL on Your
>      Private Content Objects. You can stop here if you simply want to serve
>      private content with basic URLs. Continue if you want to use signed
>      URLs.
> 5. Use the AWS web site to **create a key pair** and download the private key, which you'll use to sign the URLs. For more information about
>      creating your key pair, see Creating a Key Pair.
> 6. **Update your private content distribution** or streaming distribution to specify that the distribution's URLs **must be signed**, and who can
>      sign them. For more information, see Requiring Signed URLs.
> 7. **Create a signed URL** to give the end user. For more information, see Creating a Signed URL.